# Got another suspension?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, plagiarism

**Note:** You disagree hence you will down-vote this question, but since I have accepted an answer that doesn't really make sense since it shows I accept my mistake.

Well I wrote this answer and got suspended for plagiarism:

> 1.Lanthanoids primarily show three oxidation states(+2,+3,+4). Among these oxidation states, +3 state is the most common. Lanthanoids display a limited number of oxidation states because the energy difference between 4f,5d abd 6s orbital is quite large. On the other hand, the energy difference between 5f,6d and 7s orbitals is very less. Hence, actinoids display a large number of oxidation states.For example, uranium and plutonium display +3,+4,+5 and +6 oxidation states while neptunium displays +3,+4,+5 and +7. Te most common state in case of actinoids is also +3.
>
> 2.The 5f electrons are more effectively shielded from nuclear charge. In other words the 5f electrons themselves provide poor shielding from element to element in the series.

This was taught to me by my teacher in the class and he uses no specific book and it was written in my copy, should I write "from my copy page 16"? I told him[mod] this same thing once[for an answer on SN2]. If you're taught 2+2=4, should you tell sources for it?

Comment: I don't really see a question here, apart from your post title. In which case the answer is: yes, you have gotten another suspension.

Comment: @JonW I just wanted to discuss and get help on misusing of his powers

Comment: If you can't link to the sources you're quoting, can you at least link to the places where you quote them?

Comment: @JanDvorak simple english plz

Comment: Plagarism isn't just trying to pass of someone else's content as your own, it also means not giving credit where it is due when referencing someone else's work.

Comment: In which posts do you think you ---quoted-properly--- you didn't need to quote where a mod thought otherwise?

Comment: Well, if the content is small enough that it might have been created twice coincidentally... we can't judge that without seeing the content in question. Link please

Comment: @JanDvorak if you can see deleted one [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23825/actinoids-vs-lanthanids/26249#26249), note that I answered my question only I just put up the question because it was interesting

Comment: I can't see it. Can you quote it?

Comment: @JanDvorak added

Comment: @JanDvorak did you see it

Comment: Yeah... this definitely looks like copied from somewhere and you need to link to wherever you were copying from.

Comment: @JanDvorak there's a difference between "looks like copied" and "is copied". Well how can you say that?

Comment: As for how to attribute that specific source... be creative. Something like this should work: "transcribed from my chemistry teacher's lecture"

Comment: Are you for real? What you just posted to your defense was copied from [here](http://mya3spoint.blogspot.co.il/2013/09/important-d-and-f-clock-elements.html). People are not stupid you know, we can use something called "Google".

Comment: @ShadowWizard well I'm a CBSE student and my teacher told us this answer, I can find another site like that. e.g. [this](http://sulekharanirxiichemistry.blogspot.in/2010/12/class-xii-lanthanoids-actinoids.html). The point is "it is a back question form my Chemistry book"

Comment: So you should clearly say this in your answer. Otherwise people will think this is your original ideas, which is not true.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can do nothing to do now I'm off for 60 days. Well if it like this I better not use that stupid site.

Comment: That sounds like a wise idea...

Comment: You were busted plagiarising fair and square, accept the punishment and move on.

Comment: @SabreTooth well it may be because i'm used to at math.se and you never need citations there, anyways if you say so , judging by your rep,I think you might be right.

Comment: my rep? that means nothing am just another member. Plagiarism is basically intellectual theft and **should** always be dealt with harshly

Comment: @ADG Please see my answer below for help.

Comment: Seems like a useless question . Plagiarism is very bad and there will be a hefty punishment along with it. At the very least link your sources.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As answered by [Robert Longson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249710/280850), you have copied a text from elsewhere and did not make a reference, so this was an act of plagiarism.

Further from [this link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), please see:

> **How to reference material written by others**
>
> [Plagiarism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your answer being down-voted or deleted.
>
> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

Answer (score 7):

I searched online for the text in your answer and found [this document](http://prepareforchemistry.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/1/7/12175355/d_block.rtf)

In it is the following text:

> *Question 8.29:*
>
> *The chemistry of the actinoid elements is not so smooth as that of the Lanthanoids. Justify this statement by giving some examples from the oxidation state of these elements.*
>
> *Lanthanoids primarily show three oxidation states (+2, +3, +4). Among these oxidation states, +3 state is the most common. Lanthanoids display a limited number of oxidation states because the energy difference between 4f, 5d, and 6s orbitals is quite large. On the other hand, the energy difference between 5f, 6d, and 7s orbitals is very less. Hence, actinoids display a large number of oxidation states. For example, uranium and plutonium display +3, +4, +5, and +6 oxidation states while neptunium displays +3, +4, +5, and +7. The most common oxidation state in case of actinoids is also +3.*

Seems pretty similar to your answer except that it has fewer typos.