# Is copying documentation bad?

Tags: discussion, answers, plagiarism

If a question can be answered by copy-pasting a section from some documentation or other written source, is it bad to do so?

Should I always try to rephrase the original content, even when it is clear enough?

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249708/got-another-suspension/249711#249711

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's nothing wrong with using documentation in an answer, as long as you take care to provide attribution and make clear that it is a direct quote. A link is usually good enough for attribution; if it's hard copy documentation, you'll want to include the title and perhaps an edition, version, or year of publication. Page number's always nice, especially when [linking to a large PDF](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/how-does-pressure-treatment-affect-the-mechanical-properties-of-lumber#comment3036_2000).

The best way to make clear that something is quoted on *this platform* is to use Blockquote formatting. That's [the one that uses angle brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes); you can also highlight text and use the double-quotation mark icon in the editor (or the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>):

[image: blockquote icon screenshot]

You should definitely *not* always paraphrase external content, but sometimes it would be more appropriate, e.g.:

- The external content you need to quote is very long. One long paragraph, or three fairly short ones, is about the limit of what I *personally* feel to be short enough to quote directly in *most* answers.
- The external content you want to quote is really hard to understand, *or* the user asking the question indicates they have already read it and didn't understand it. Then you should definitely explain *in your own words*.
- You think the full content of the linked documentation is important to read in full. This is more of a grey area—while you should still answer the question as fully as reasonably possible *right there in the body of the answer*, you might want to only *mention* some extra considerations to keep your answer concise.

That said, **if your answer consists of nothing more than a direct quote**, take a moment before you hit "Submit" to consider:

- Does this quote clearly contain all the information needed to solve the problem?
- Can I add some clarifying details, perhaps an example, that would make this answer much more useful than just a quote?
- Is the question on-topic and not a duplicate?

If you're not sure the question is a good fit for the community where it was posted, you can flag it, vote to close, or ask for other opinions in one of the community's chat rooms. Some users prefer to do this before or in lieu of answering.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're not pretending that you wrote the information and provide a link (or reference) to the source, it's not bad at all.

In fact, it might even be considered a good thing in that you're helping educate people on how to help themselves in the future.

Comment: When you just give people an answer that they could have trivially found by simply bothering to *look* for it, you're not teaching them how to help themselves.  You're teaching them that they don't have to help themselves and that they can simply ask SO users to google their questions for them without bothering to do even the most trivial of research.

Comment: @Servy: Not if they don't know where to look. By linking back to the source they'll know for next time.

Comment: If they couldn't have found it on their own, then you're not teaching them how to help themselves.  They haven't learned how to find something they don't know about, they've just learned how to ask someone else to find something they didn't know about.  (Which isn't necessarily wrong, but it's still not them learning to help themselves.)

Answer (score 1):

From [How to reference material written by others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from
>   another site or in an answer on Meta Stack Exchange) make sure you do
>   all of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author